# Designing 'plugins' - How to pass an object method in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, plugins, static-methods

I'm not sure if this is possible or maybe more imporantly good design.
Feedback on both appreciated.

We have a front end that we add functional elements to through 'plugins'.
The plugin design is a javascript object with some data and some methods as below:

```
function FeedbackPlugin(){
  return {
    name: "Feedback",
    help: "Provide feedback on any element of the site",
    ...    
    showForm : function(_feedbackType) {
      ...
    },
    ...
    messageCallbacks: [{callbackKey:"ProvideFeedback",callbackHandler:showForm}]       
  };
}
```

The framework loads each plugin and then iterates over the **messageCallbacks** to tie comet events to plugin methods.

Sadly the code above does not work.  The plugin's **showForm** method is not in scope when the framework tries to register it.  I think we may need to pass a pointer to the **showForm** method of an existing plugin instance...

- Is there any way in javascript to
  somehow make this method static?
- Should the method just live outside
  the plugin for convenience sake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each plugin being loaded is static (contains no varying data), then load them as scripts instead of JSON. If there is data that's dynamic, then separate the dynamic data from the static functions, and send only the data as JSON.